# Is it possible to code sign and publish a Visual Studio Click Once app using a USB Token?

Tags: visual-studio

I currently sign my ClickOnce apps within the Visual Studio "Publish" workflow using a .pfx file. I would like to eliminate the .pfx and use a USB token. Has anyone done this? I don't want to go the SignTool route, I like the automation of the current workflow. If I understand correctly when a USB token is plugged in the certificate appears as if it's in the certificate store. It should work but these pieces are expensive. Just trying to check first.

Comment: Having this answered is critical because, in June 2023, we cannot sign code anymore without a token. Have you found the solution?

Comment: I found your question here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/822049/how-do-i-sign-a-visual-studio-application-with-an